# Next Non-blank cell in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the **next non blank cell** of a column.

I would like to find a way to do it with something already existing (without a custom loop).

For example, I searched around the `Find` function :

```
item = Worksheets(ws).Columns(1).Find(what:= something , after:= previousitem)
```

But here I would need a `what:=` parameters, which mean non blank

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: ......What:="*"

Comment: What:="*" works quite fine until the last one. But it return the first row of the column at the end

Comment: You just need to check the returned address to know when you're done.

Comment: Yes that's what i'll do. But i was wondering why i did not get "nothing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this works :

```
item = Worksheets(ws).Columns(1).Find(what:= "*" , after:= previousitem)
```

Comment: But the Find does not return nothing on the last item, but the first item of the list

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, using following key combination:

```
Ctrl + Arrow-Down
```

Record this in a macro and Excel will generate the correct VBA code for it.